# set the default application to open a particular single file on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8

this question has been answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/635086/how-do-i-set-the-default-application-to-open-a-single-file-on-windows-7-and-8) before but has only been answered for windows 7 not windows 8. will someone please provide a solution for this in windows 8?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/choose-programs-windows-uses-default this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution you linked to is applicable for Windows 8 as well.  The only part that has changed is how you set a default program.

1.) Set the default program for the file extension.

- Right click on file > "Open With" > "Choose Default Program..."
- Select the program you want to open this kind of file by default

2.) To handle the exception, create a shortcut.

- Right click on your desktop > "New" > "Shortcut"
- Click "Browse..." and navigate to the program to want to open the exception, then append the full path/filename of the exception.  You'll end up with something like this:

  > "C:\Program Files\Python\python.exe" "C:\Users\immortalsquish\Desktop\awesome_script.py"
- Click "Next", name your shortcut, then click "Finish".